# Disable mouse wheel scrolling on ListBox

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, scroll

I have a `ListBox` on an MVC page:

```
@Html.ListBox("lstFacilitySelection", Model.FacilityOptionList, new { id = "FacilityListBox", Multiple = "multiple", Size = 5, style = "width: 50%;" })
```

How can I disable the mouse's wheel scrolling for this ListBox, so that the scroll bar at the side of the control has to be used?

**Edit:** The solution as proposed by Ashwini Verma with a slight modification:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FacilityListBox').on({
        'mousewheel': function (e) {
            if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I'd advise adding at least the [tag:javascript] tag to get some more attention. The short answer is that this isn't easily doable. I suspect it will require a lot of javascript and CSS trickery. You might have to use something that emulates a multi-select rather than the built-in HTML component itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it using jquery.
[**See working demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jR63W/).

```
<div class="scrollable"> </div>

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('body').on({
        'mousewheel': function(e) {
            if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'd modify it to disable the scrolling only on the desired control, not the entire page then specifying certain parts to be scrollable. I'll append this to my question.